# How to get the shard key of a given collection with MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-shell

For investigation purpose I need to get the shardkey of a given MongoDB collection.

`db.getSiblingDB("mydb").mycollection.getIndexes()` gives all indexes.
`db.getSiblingDB("mydb").mycollection.getShardDistribution()` gives the distribution among shards.

What is the command to use in order to get the shard key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `db.printShardingStatus()`. See documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)